# Javascript array to Excel - Styling

Tags: javascript, excel, activexobject

Thanks to GBI's code ([Export array of objects into Excel using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008593/export-array-of-objects-into-excel-using-javascript)), I was able to export an array of objects to javascript, see my code below.  My question about this is, can I do any excel styling?  The title will be my header, and I want to add borders, bold, etc. but there doesn't seem to be any option for styling.

```
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\REPORT.csv", true);
        var title = "GROUP, HOURS TYPE, EMPLOYEE TYPE, PREV, JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC, TOTAL";
        s.WriteLine(title);

        s.Close();
        alert("Report Saved as C:\\REPORT.csv");
```

Comment: csv doesn't support styling.  You would probably have to find a way to export a true excel file.

Comment: Irk, I think you're right.  I wasn't thinking that this is actually writing to a text file.  There are no cells, so there's nothing to style.  Back to the drawing board......

Comment: I've always made excel files on the backend, usually c# of vb.net.  Not sure if that's an option for you -- if not it looks like there might be a few js libraries that can do it

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if is there a way in javascript, but if you are using php check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3969030/6495164

EDIT: PHP Excel is here: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/